# how to set database content as a message on application startup?

Tags: android, message, startup

I have one database table "TABLE_TIPS" with two value
1. tips_id (auto increment)
2. Tips
I need to set tips as message on application startup. whenever user open application it show
one tips as message at a time.I search lot's of artical but didn't find any helpful.
Suppose i have 10 tips then application show one tips at a time and next tips on next time
When it reach on 10 then it show from beginning  again..
I don't understand how to do this.
Please provide me reference or related artical.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It must show one tips at a time,not necessary it must in a sequence,randomly also acceptable....

Comment: On toast or may be alert box....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Shared preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

It useful for you.